# Store month and year in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have following date:

```
$params['ExpirationMonth'];
$params['ExpirationYear'];
```

I need some suggestion regarding how can I store only month and year in mysql database. After some research I have found 3 ways to do it.

1) I can use 1st as the days and can store along with month and year.

2) Instead of using `date` I can use `varchar` datatype and can only store month and year in it.

3) I can store the two as two separate columns as integers. i.e. for month and year.

Which is the better way?. Need some suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: What do you plan to do with YY and MM? E.g. do you need to search upon card numbers that expire in 2012? No?

Comment: @SalmanA : right I am doing something like that

Comment: It is credit cards, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `date` column, keeping in mind that:

- You could set the day portion to 1
- The card is good for the entire month of the specified expiry date. `0512` means valid through 31 May 2012.

Advantages:

- Sorting is straight forward (compared to storing as varchar)
- Date operations are straight forward (compared to storing as varchar/two integer columns)
- Data stays in one column (compared to storing as two integer columns)

Sample queries:

```sql
-- expires in 2012
WHERE expires >= '2012-01-01' AND expires < '2012-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
-- expires in Dec 2012
WHERE expires >= '2012-12-01' AND expires < '2012-12-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Comment: But why didn't you store the last valid date `2012-05-31`? Selection would be easier `WHERE expire_date >= CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: @SirRufo: yes that is possible (and makes sense).

Answer (score 2):

1) I can use 1st as the days and can store along with month and year.

> This option is better as if there is any calculation or sorting need
>   to be done, it will be useful and handy.

2) Instead of using date I can use varchar datatype and can only store month and year in it.

3)  I can store the two as two separate columns as integers. i.e. for month and year.

> For above two option are fine as it will take less space as compare to
>   date or timestamp. But you can do calucation or orderby with this. For
>   calculation you need to convert it date by "str_to_date" function

I hope this will help you in some way.

Comment: Thanks...but what you think about 2nd option?

Answer (score 1):

stored as UNIX. suddenly need to add something in the future, and no problem to get anything out of date

Answer (score 1):

Expiration Month/Year from credit cards means that this card is valid until the end of this Month/Year.

Best way to store as a comparable date you should get the last day of this month

```
STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( '01,', @Month, ',', @Year, '%d,%m,%Y ) 
  + INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
  - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always store it like YYYYDD as an integer:
So for May 2021 you can store this integer: 202105